# getSymbols issues with the date R

Tags: r, get, symbols, stock

I am trying to get the stock price of ATT since 1984. I wrote this code:

```
from.dat <- as.Date("07/19/84", format="%m/%d/%y")
to.dat <- as.Date("11/07/13", format="%m/%d/%y")
getSymbols("ATT", from = from.dat, to =   to.dat)
```

However, the earliest data I could get is from Jun of 2008. Could you please help me?

Comment: Tags could use some editing: e.g. the programming language used might be helpful in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a string for the from date:

```
getSymbols("ATT", from = '1984-07-19')
```

Based on [this blog post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2009q3/004704.html), the `to` date is always today's date.